# Ag - Grid export dropdown in grid to excel using processCellCallback

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I am using below function to handle export to excel. I am using **exportDataAsExcel**  provided by grid api to extract data. Below is my code snippet -

```
public exportDataToExcel (excelParams: any){
    excelParams = {
            processCellCallback (excelParams: any) => {
            if(excelParams.column.getColId() === 'myCol' && excelParams.value){
                cost modifiedValue = ['value1','value2','value3'];
                return modifiedValue;   
            } else {
                return excelParams.value;
            }
        }  
    },
    fileName: "myfile"
    allColumns: true
    };
    gridApi.exportDataAsExcel(excelParams);
}
```

My requirement is to export the **myCol** column values as drop down in excel. Hence I have tried passing a single array as modified value. But that didn't work. It prints the array in excel. To clarify my requirement further, let's say the column **myCol** has a value **value1** in grid. When I import the grid my excel should populate value1 in myCol and value1 cell should have a drop down where I can select value1, value2 and value3. please see attached screenshot for requirement -

[image]

Is there anyway I can achieve it ?

Comment: as per docs ag grid only exports data that you see in the grid. https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-export/#what-gets-exported For features like these, you might want to implement export grid on the server side in which you have more control

Comment: @PratikBhat Thanks Pratik for the comment. I am aware of the fact that ag export only return a string . The reason why I asked  is I just wanted to know if we can pass single array to excel params and excel could detect is as a dropdown.

Comment: may be you missed my point, the filtering dropdown you see in excel is not supported by ag-grid since it is more like a cell rendering feature. Refer to the link I posted to Know what gets exported. Server side export is your best bet